# Как называются мониторы для программистов?

Tags: железо, экран

Вы наверняка где-то то видели или сами владеете дополнительными экранами к монитору для программирования.  Они бывают иногда вертикальными и длинными. Чисто для кода.  Не нужен fullhd. Я хочу себе пару таких но даже не знаю как они называются.

[image]

Comment: Никак. Просто мониторы. Втыкаются в видеокарту. А любой монитор с VESA-дырками на хорошей подставке и с программной поддержкой можно использовать "на боку", вертикально и длинно.

Comment: @D-side я приложил фотку. Тоесть то что справа это просто повернутый монитор??? Неужели это не отдельный продукт? Сложно поверить. Ведь есть потребитель и продукт соответственно должен быть. Сложно поверить что так часто просто поворачивают мониторы

Comment: По расположению логотипа и лампочки можно предположить, что это обычный широкий монитор, поставленный боком :)

Comment: @andreymal окей.  Пример не удачный. Да согласен сдесь скорее похоже на повернутый экран.  Но я подобное часто видел.  Неужто везде просто тупо поворачивали?

Comment: Ну по крайней мере лично я нигде не встречал именно вертикальных мониторов, всегда повёрнутые попадались

Comment: А зачем изобретать что-то новое, если всё что требуется, уже есть? Берём любой монитор, вешаем на поворачиваемую VESA-лапу, указываем в панели управления видяхой поворот монитора -- готово. Разумеется, есть мониторы, у которых поворачиваемость встроена в подставку. И у которых даже есть автопереключение разрешения при повороте (если вдруг вы вертите мониторы каждый день...). Но посмотрите на цены "при прочих равных" и спросите себя, нужно ли вам это, или лучше употребить разницу на более качественную ЖК-панель. Зачем отказываться от FullHD (или чего покрепче)?

Comment: @D-side как я представляю себе это: вертикальный экран с низким разрешением без "ножки" чтобы подкреплялся с боку на основной экран. Дешево, по существу и надобно. Притом не нужны всякие тройники и миллионы кабелей подстолом. Подключил к основному hdmi и он раздал его эти вертикалкам. Согласитесь. Звучит как нужная вещь. Не может быть чтоб не продавали. "Поворачивать" это выглядит убого. А как отдельный продукт это круто. Вспомните аналогию с ноутбуками - трансформерами. Которые из мобильника превращается в ноут и планшет.  Никомуже они не понравилось. Провал на рынке.

Comment: @D-side ...люди любят отдельные специализированные продукты подточенные под конкретные нужды

Comment: Такие решения выдвигались **для ноутбуков**, поищите на кикстартерах. Но то, что я видел, имело отвратительные ЖК-панели и функционировало со встроенной **в устройство же** видеокарты (DisplayLink, что бесит пользователей Linux отсутствием поддержки уже давно). И когда я в последний раз туда смотрел, там вкладчики забористо ругались в комментариях на отсутствие признаков жизни авторов. Решение с повёрнутым монитором при равной цене работает от нормальной видеокарты, имеет куда лучшую и большую панель, стоит столько же, поддерживается куда лучше. А провода надо спланировать и развести один раз.

Comment: Линукс вообще. Крутая вещь. Но вместо с удобствами с ней приходят и проблемы несоответствий,отсутствий и тд... спасибо за дельные советы

Comment: Да неподдержка Linux ещё терпима, есть виртуальные машины на крайняк. Но вот то, что за те же деньги в таком формате можно обзавестись лишь мелкой TN-панелькой разрешением 1366х768, вместо нормального 23" IPS с 1920х1080 -- грустно.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не по теме

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет отдельных вертикальных мониторов. Есть мониторы с возможностью поворота на 90 градусов. Т.е. это опция, а не отдельный вид техники. [**вот пример**](https://youtu.be/QWg_tmuR1jE?t=305)